# Make the Web App on Azure portal only Available few hours in a Week

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I am building a ASP.Net Core Web App which I am trying to host in the Azure portal. We have requirement that these Applications can be accessed only certain times in a week, those times are stored in the Azure Database. Is it possible to make the App Available/Accessible to the users upon looking at database

[image]

Here the Setting is that the application should be available only between 14:00 - 16:30 on TUESDAY. When I tried to research we can schedule tasks/workflows in the portal but couldnt find what I am looking for. All I wanted to know is this requirement possible, if so please share the idea.. I am new  Web App development and Azure deployment, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in Azure out of the box. This is something you will have to handle yourself.

One obvious way to implement this would be to check if the application should be available on every request. If the request day and time falls between the available times set in the database, you show your users the website content otherwise show them some kind of not available message.

A more complicated way would be to make use of `App_offline.htm` file to make your site unavailable. You can dynamically add/delete `App_offline.htm` file to your WebApp based on the day/time when you want your site to be offline/online.

However please note that while your site is offline, you will still be charged for the WebApp as the resources keep remain provisioned.

Comment: Thank you so much if we plan to go ahead and hosting application on prem will the 1st option work..? How does the 1st one work, so when the Call to the App is made, inside the home controller call the Settings tables in the DB and check against current datetime? If we have enabled the Azure AD Authentication wont the Call to the application by default goes the Authentication?

Comment: `How does the 1st one work, so when the Call to the App is made, inside the home controller call the Settings tables in the DB and check against current datetime?` - You can certainly do that. If this information does not change often, you can also cache it so that you don't have to make repeated database calls. `If we have enabled the Azure AD Authentication wont the Call to the application by default goes the Authentication?` - I think it will but only thing the user will be able to do is just login. Once they login into the application, they will be shown the site offline message.

Comment: `if we plan to go ahead and hosting application on prem will the 1st option work` - Both of these options will work regardless of where you host your application. 1st option is application specific and the 2nd option is web server specific (IIS, if I am not mistaken). HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Is it possible to using a time trigger function to call [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/stop) to stop the service?

Comment: @TinyWang - Of course. But stopping the web application will make it inaccessible and the users will get some error. I am not sure if this is what OP is looking for. My understanding is that OP would want the web application available all the time but users will only be able to access it between certain times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir : ) You're thoughtful

Comment: @TinyWang Can the time trigger function on the Azure refer to the Azure DB to check when tha app needs to hosted/stopped?

Comment: @GauravMantri Sorry for not being clear.  We can even have the application go inaccessible but just make the app available only between the time that is given in the database.. Can then time trigger function on Azure be used here, again can it refer to the Azure DB to check when the start and end time and then host the app/stopped?

Comment: No worries. Yeah, in that case you can use Timer Triggered Azure Function that will run on a scheduled basis to check if the application should be available/unavailable. In this Function, you can query the database to find this information.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. This really help

Comment: @trx Yes, function time trigger can realize it as Gaurav Mantri sir said.

Comment: @TinyWang I was searching for an example of an timed trigger azure function that does lookup at the DB.. Do you have any references to help me get started that will be really appreciated.. New to Application building and the azure platrform and kind of stuck .. Thanks again

Comment: @trx Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup) help you?

Comment: @TinyWang Thank you It did help. I am in the process of building a Azure function an ran in to an issue which is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723458/calling-the-post-api-call-from-the-timer-triggered-azure-function can you please help me with it

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Azure Automation Service** to orchestrate processes like this. You will have to create a runbook (script in python or powershell) that will query the DB and figure out the times when the **Azure Website** hosting your webapplication should be started or stopped.

Comment: I believe OP does not want the site to be stopped. The intent is to show some kind of site not available message.

Comment: If we are going with this option to take the site down on other days then we may charged  only on those days/time the application is hosted?

Comment: `If we are going with this option to take the site down on other days then we may charged only on those days/time the application is hosted?` - No, you will still be charged. To stop the billing you will have to delete the WebApp resource completely.

Comment: @GauravMantri Is this something easily achievable? Since I am new to the Web App development I what to choose the easier solution

Comment: I can only think of these two options :).